# Handling Radio Buttons in Forms with React (Rails 5.1)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, reactjs, radio-button

I'm having difficulty understanding how to handle radio buttons in forms with other types of inputs in React.  I'm working from an example that incorporates string type input fields and another for pure radio buttons, but not sure how to get them to play nice together.  The text field inputs work fine, but I can't get the radio button feature to work.

The basic theory behind the radio button of the React portion of this form is the checkbox for each option is set when a user clicks on a button and the checked value for that particular button is set to true via a logic check, while the other radio buttons are set to false.

I'm not sure how to integrate the handling of the input fields with the radio buttons.

Any guidance on this would be great!

Here's my form jsx:

```
class Project_form extends React.Component {

handleChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const obj = {};
    obj[name] = e.target.value;
    this.props.onUserInput(obj);
}

handleOptionChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.id;
    const obj = {};
    obj[name] = e.target.checked;
    this.props.onChangeInput(obj);
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onFormSubmit();
}

render() {

    return (

        <form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)} >

              <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                    id="project_name" 
                    className="form-control"                       
                    type="text" 
                    name="project_name" 
                    placeholder="Enter Your Project Name"
                    value={this.props.project_name}
                    onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                    id="project_zipcode" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    type="text" 
                    name="project_zipcode" 
                    placeholder="Zipcode"
                    value={this.props.project_zipcode}
                    onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}  />
              </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>How Soon Do You Want this Project Started?</label>
                    <div className="radio">

                      <p><input type="radio" 
                        value="1-2 Weeks" 
                        name="project_timeframe" 
                        id="project_timeframe_1-2_weeks"
                        checked={this.props.project_timeframe === 'ASAP'} 
                        onChange={(event) => this.handleOptionChange(event)}  />
                      <label>As Soon As Possible</label></p>

                      <p><input type="radio" 
                        value="2-4 Weeks" 
                        name="project_timeframe" 
                        id="project_timeframe_2-4_weeks"
                        checked={this.props.project_timeframe === '2-4 Weeks'} 
                        onChange={(event) => this.handleOptionChange(event)} />
                      <label>2-4 Weeks</label></p>

                      <p><input type="radio" 
                        value="4-6 Weeks" 
                        name="project_timeframe" 
                        id="project_timeframe_4-6_weeks"
                        checked={this.props.project_timeframe === '4-6 Weeks'} 
                        onChange={(event) => this.handleOptionChange(event)} />
                      <label>4-6 Weeks</label></p>

                     <p><input type="radio" 
                        value="More Than 6 Weeks" 
                        name="project_timeframe" 
                        id="project_timeframe_more_than_6_weeks"
                        checked={this.props.project_timeframe === 'More Than 6 Weeks'} 
                        onChange={(event) => this.handleOptionChange(event)} />
                      <label>More Than 6 Weeks</label></p>

                    </div> 
                </div>

             <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                    type="submit"                       
                    value="Create Project" 
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
                     />
             </div>
        </form>
        )
}
}
```

Here's my main component, which sets the state of the app.

```
class Projects extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        projects: this.props.projects,
        project_name: '',
        project_zipcode: '',
        selectedTimeframeOption: 'ASAP'
    } 
}

handleUserInput(obj) {
    this.setState(obj);
}

handleChangeInput(obj) {
    this.setState({
    selectedOption: obj.target.value
  });
}

handleFormSubmit() {
    const project = {
        name: this.state.project_name, 
        zipcode: this.state.project_zipcode, 
        timeframe: this.state.project_timeframe
    };
    $.post('/projects',
        {project: project})
        .done((data) => {
            this.addNewProject(data);
        });
}

addNewProject(project){
    const projects = update(this.state.projects, { $push: [project]});
    this.setState({
        projects: projects.sort(function(a,b){
            return new Date(a['updated_at']) - new Date(b['updated_at']);
        })
    });
}

render() {
    return (

        <div>
           <h2>Start a New Project</h2>
                <a  href="/projects/new/" 
                    className="btn btn-large btn-success">Create a New Project</a>
                {/* <%= link_to "Create a New Project", new_project_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %> */}

                    <Project_form 
                        project_name={this.state.project_name} 
                        project_zipcode={this.state.project_zipcode} 
                        project_timeframe={this.state.selectedTimeframeOption}
                        onUserInput={(obj) => this.handleUserInput(obj)}
                        onFormSubmit={() => this.handleFormSubmit()} />

                {/* <% if @current_user.projects.any? %> */}                    
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Existing Projects</h3>
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <Project_list projects={this.state.projects} />
                    </div>                              
                </div>                  
        </div>

        )
}
}
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste your jsx code + HTML structure in a https://codepen.io draft so we can see what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  Had to play around with getting the event object into the stateful component.

My form file now has this event handler added:

```
handleOptionChange(e) {
    const option = e.target.name;
    const obj = {};
    obj[option] = e.target.value;
    this.props.onUserInput(obj);

}
```

Then this.props.onUserInput(obj); gets called by the existing method in the Project.jsx file and I got rid of the handleChangeInput method.

```
handleUserInput(obj) {
    this.setState(obj);
}
```

The state then flows down to the Project_form Component here:

```
<Project_form 
        project_name={this.state.project_name} 
        project_zipcode={this.state.project_zipcode} 
        project_timeframe={this.state.project_timeframe}
        onUserInput={(obj) => this.handleUserInput(obj)}
        onFormSubmit={() => this.handleFormSubmit()} />
```